# Change form list default value

Tags: theming, 8, hooks

I want to change the default -select a value- from a text list to a something like -please select a choice-

[image]

This is what I have:

```
  function project_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
    if($form['#id'] == 'edit-field-gen-list'){
    $form['field_gen_list']['#default_value'] = 'all';
    }
}
```

It's not picking up the value.

[image]

This is the HTML.

Comment: Are you sure that $form_id is **edit-field-gen-list**. I think it's **edit_field_gen_list**. Try kint($form_id) to see it.

Comment: i have tried that too --- its not picking it up... its a text list on a contact form

Comment: Better you need kint($form) and show it on question. It's better for your question.

Answer (score 4):

- In Drupal 8 type-hint `$form_state` with the [FormStateInterface](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Form!FormStateInterface.php/interface/FormStateInterface/8.2.x) & do not pass it by reference:

  ```
  hook_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id)
  ```

  See [hook_form_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Form!form.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/8.2.x) for further reference.
- I see some confusion on your usage of the `$form_id` / `$form['#id']`. Dump your `$form_id` in the hook & see which is the correct form you want to alter. Because as others have mentioned already: `edit-field-gen-list` is not your form id but your `field_gen_list` field id. For example: the form id of the contact Website feedback is `contact_message_feedback_form`.
- Given the HTML in your question, your `$form['field_gen_list']['widget']['#options']` will not have a key for 'all'. So adding that as default value will not work unless you add such a key value to the options array

  So instead try this:

  ```
  function project_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id)
  {
      kint($form_id, 'Find correct form id');

      if ($form_id == 'contact_message_feedback_form') { // Change this

          // Add an 'all' key value option
          $form['field_gen_list']['widget']['#options']['all'] = '- All -';

          // Set newly added key 'all' as default value
          $form['field_gen_list']['widget']['#default_value'] = 'all';
      }

  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function project_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'edit-field-gen-list') {
    $form['field_gen_list']['#default_value'] = 'all';
  }
}
```

I'm not quite sure if the form element is in `$form['field_gen_list']` though.

Comment: I tried it as you posted and also without the `$form['field_gen_list']` -- still not working ... Btw is a text list created for contact form.

Comment: Just to be sure: you're using Drupal 8, and not Drupal 7?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this:

```
$form['field_gen_list']['und']['#default_value'] = 'all';
```

Note: All is your key value on select list.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: i think in your select list not have  'all' key and value. like: <option value="all"> All </option>

Comment: tried it still no result... 
`  function project_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    if ($form_id == 'edit-field-gen-list') {
      $form['field_gen_list']['und']['#default_value'] = 'all';
    }
  }`

Answer (score 1):

In your code, replace the line $form['field_gen_list']['#default_value'] = 'all'; by:

```
// save the array of field options in a var.
$field_options = $form['field_gen_list']['und']['#options'];
// change the value of the '_none' key to the one you need.
$field_options['_none'] = '- please select a choice -';
// set the modified array of options as the options for this field
$form['field_gen_list']['und']['#options'] = $field_options;
```

That's it!!